# Как сделать чтобы из textView нельзя было удалить текст?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, apple

В своем приложении я использую TextView для того чтобы отобразить информацию на экране
информацию я пишу в коде.Все работает но проблема когда я запускаю симулятор и проверяю приложение как пользователь то я могу удалить информацию или вообще напечатать что-то свое.У меня приложение рассчитано на чтение информации а не на то что пользователь пишет свои заметки.Вопрос состоит как сделать так чтобы пользователь не мог удалить мою информацию и напечатать свою?Чтобы было более понятно я прикрепил видео: https://youtu.be/PDI9CVTHlfo

Answer (score 1):

```
textView.editable = false
```

Или можно в XCode галку снять.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам нужно только отображать информацию, используйте `UILabel`. Для многострочности в коде:

```
label.numberOfLines = 0
```

В Interface Builder:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]